# What does OPEN means in LAST_REQUEST_TYPE in DB2?

Tags: db2, transaction, db2-luw

In Db2 v11.5.7 on Linux I would like to monitor what is last request made by application. I assume one of application does not closes transaction properly.

To simplify the data I collected, I have the following SQL that returns application ID and the last application request:

```
SELECT
   APPLICATION_HANDLE,
   LAST_REQUEST_TYPE
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_CONNECTION(NULL,-2))
```

In LAST_REQUEST_TYPE column the following is returned:

- EXECUTE: database is executing SQL statement
- CLOSE: database executed SQL, but no commit or rollback has been executed
- FETCH: usually complex select statement and database is fetching data from database
- COMMIT: application executed commit
- ROLLBACK: application executed rollback
- INTERNAL27: ???
- OPEN: ???

Question: What is INTERNAL27 and specially what is OPEN status?

Comment: The presence of FETCH and CLOSE should give you a hint of what OPEN means.

Comment: I assumed it is related. But what exact "action" is performed at OPEN request type? I see plenty of connections with OPEN request type with OUW START TIME few days back. Is OPEN like: creating cursor in stored procedure, but not yet calling SQL to be executed like FETCH operation? If this is true, then transaction is still on going and probably some locking on tables is it?

Comment: @folow Look at the [OPEN statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-open) description.